# Column-based time partitioning in BigQuery via Java API Client Library

Tags: google-bigquery

Partitioning via a column-based timestamp is currently available as an Alpha feature that we are utilizing via CLI. Creating and loading data via CLI works as intended when passing in the table schema (which is a necessity for using this alpha feature) and the column to partition on with properly formatted Avro data. However, we'd like to take advantage of the Java API Client Library (com.google.api.services.bigquery) as we are aware that the Cloud Client Library does not yet support columnar time-based partitioning.

The issue we are encountering is that the library requires a TableSchema be passed as part of the JobConfigurationLoad. This works fine with a small schema of a few fields, but for larger table schemas manually creating this object becomes a bit cumbersome. The documentation for the Alpha feature gives an example where a JSON schema is passed as part of the insert body call, but this is in the Python API Client which we are unable to leverage for our use case.

Is there anywhere in the Java API Client Library we can leverage the use of a JSON schema file like this for creating a table (and subsequently loading records) with a time-based column partitioning field? If not - is there a plan to support this in the Cloud Client Library when the feature is rolled out?

Thank you!

Comment: You may wish to file this as an issue / feature request on https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/issues

Comment: You shouldn't need to specify the schema when loading Avro. BigQuery should extract the schema from the Avro file. This sounds like a bug if you have to.

Comment: @HuaZhang Correct, specifying a schema for a self-describing format is not a necessity when working with bq in production. However, it's necessary when you want to use the Alpha feature that we're working with - you will receive an error message along the lines of 'BigQuery error in load operation: Table with field based partitioning must have a schema.'

Comment: Thanks for confirming the error message. We should be able use the schema in the Avro file. Did you file a bug as Tim suggested? Otherwise I'll file a bug internally to track this issue. Thanks again for reporting the issue.

Comment: Good to know! I haven't filed a bug yet so please do. When you do also please share the issue so I can keep an eye on the status - very excited to use this feature. Thanks again!

Comment: Created https://b.corp.google.com/issues/70794247 to track this.

Comment: Above link requires a login (seems to be "corporate internal"). So I guess that the public issue is: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70794247